# Viewpager disable last page on swipe and on tab

Tags: android, android-viewpager

my aim to disable both tabing and swiping to the last page
 when user click on last page or tried to swipe to last page i want callback so that  i can show toast ..

currently i am following this but not able to make

```
public class CustomSwipeViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean mLastPageEnabled = false;
private int mLastPageIndex = 0;

public NoSwipeViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public NoSwipeViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setLastPageEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mLastPageEnabled = enabled;
}

public void setLastPageIndex(int index) {
    mLastPageIndex = index;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

    if(!mLastPageEnabled && getCurrentItem() >= (mLastPageIndex - 1)) {
        // Always return false to disable user swipes
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (!mLastPageEnabled && getCurrentItem() >= (mLastPageIndex - 1)) {
        // Always return false to disable user swipes
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Hope this will work as you want.

```
@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {



        if (!mLastPageEnabled && getCurrentItem() > (mLastPageIndex - 1)) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                    x1 = event.getX();
                    y1 = event.getY();
                    break;
                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP): {
                    x2 = event.getX();
                    y2 = event.getY();
                    dx = x2 - x1;
                    dy = y2 - y1;

                    // Use dx and dy to determine the direction
                    if (Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy)) {
                        if (dx > 0) {
                            //right//previous
                            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
                        } else {
                            //left//next
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         return false;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }


        }

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (!mLastPageEnabled && getCurrentItem() > (mLastPageIndex - 1)) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                    x1 = event.getX();
                    y1 = event.getY();
                    break;
                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP): {
                    x2 = event.getX();
                    y2 = event.getY();
                    dx = x2 - x1;
                    dy = y2 - y1;

                    // Use dx and dy to determine the direction
                    if (Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy)) {
                        if (dx > 0) {
                            //right//previous
                            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
                        } else {
                            //left//next
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         return false;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }


        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: how i can stop on tab click also

Comment: swipe also not working ,, i am able to swipe 0->1 and then 1->2 is disable but i am not able to swipe back 1->0

Comment: ya basically i want  0->1 on  and 1->0 on and 1->2 off but when some condition true i will make 1->2 enable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107944/discussion-between-andro-and-janki-gadhiya).

Comment: with your new code 1-0 0-1 is working but now i can move 1-2 also
its moving very slow from 1->2

Comment: Now ? check it plz

Comment: still he i am able to move to 1-2 with slow effect

Comment: i added  case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) full code to actiondown also now its working

Comment: ant idea how i can disbale same thing in tab on click

Comment: for tab can you give where i have to ? i am using TAbLayout

Comment: put the code of your activity containing tab layout.

Comment: some time it laggy while swiping

Comment: The reason is we are doing to much processing in Touch event. Its will not be laggy in Device with large RAM . but the effect will be there as you need a `NON DEFAULT` functionality for a View pager.

Comment: like if i do fast swiping then i am able to go to last page , but its only half page visible